# Excluding exotic PL structures on S^4

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 4-manifolds

Suppose you have a finite group $G<SO(5)$ such that $S^4/G$ is homeomorphic to $S^4$ and such that $S^4/G$ is a PL manifold with respect to a PL structure induced by a standard structure on $S^4$. Is there a general argument by which $S^4/G$ is a standard PL $4$-sphere?

More precisely: $\mathbb{R}^5$ has a canonical PL structure which induces a PL structure on $\mathbb{R}^5/G$ (cf. https://eudml.org/doc/210089). $S^4/G$ is then meant to be the link of $\overline{0}$ in $\mathbb{R}^5/G$.

*Example:* Take $G$ to be the exotic image of the alternating group $A_5$ in the symmetric group $S_6<SO(5)$. In this case one can check by hand that $S^4/G$ is a standard PL $4$-sphere, but in the way I do it it is very cumbersome.

Comment: Can you explain this example?

Comment: In this special example one can construct a fundamental domain for the action of $G$ on $S^4$. Examining the identifications on the boundary that have to be carried out to obtain $S^4/G$ carefully shows that $S^4/G$ is a standard PL sphere (cf. http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=im&paperid=1420&option_lang=eng, Theorem 1.3)